# Почему не выходит обратиться из метода класса к свойству, содержащему массив?

Tags: php, массивы, api, объекты, класс

Коллеги!

Подключаюсь к api по средством следующего кода:

```
 class Auth {
        public $url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        public $credentials = [
            'user_name' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'user_pass' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'product_code' => 'api'
            ];
        
            public function moveaway () {
                **$access = json_encode($this->credentials);
                echo $this->access;**
                $getting = curl_init($this->url);
                curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $access);
                curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($getting, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                $output = curl_exec($getting);
                curl_close($getting);
                echo $output;
            }
        }
```

Заметил, что если обращаться внутри функции к переменной, содержащей массив, то чем бы это не делалось - выдается NULL. Если выводить массив вне класса, то все нормально.. Обращаться к $credentials пробовал разными способами: var_dump($this -> credentials), print_r(), moveaway::$credentials...

Ничего не понимаю, может в классе просто нельзя использовать некоторые типы массивов? В интернете ничего на этот счет не нашел..

Comment: `echo $access;` $access - обчная переменная функции

Comment: тоже, увы, не срабатывает..

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9040e505808d167da016b7ed2cdbf4d9f476265d

Comment: @splash58 забавно я написал точно такой же код ))) https://3v4l.org/i2WeS

Comment: если echo $access, то просто белый экран..

Comment: @Ипатьев ну, а вариатов-то не много :)

Comment: А как вы собственно вызываете этот метод? Как именно вы вызывали `var_dump($this -> credentials) ` внутри этого класса в каком либо методе или просто от балды вызвали? `moveaway::$credentials` это только для статических переменных и при этом надо обращаться к классу `Auth::$credentials`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, тупо не обратился к методу:

```
$h = new Auth();
$h->moveaway();
```

Всем спасибо за помощь и извините, бога ради, что побеспокоил..